# EntityFramework tries to select a none existing column?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, redmine

I have an issue and I just can't figure out what is causing the issue.

I have a redmine database with a 'journals' table http://puu.sh/1iRIt. 
Using the Visual Studio 2012 plugin EntityFramework Power Tools this has been reverse engineered into the following class:

```
public class Journal
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int journalized_id { get; set; }
        public string journalized_type { get; set; }
        public int user_id { get; set; }
        public string notes { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime created_on { get; set; }
    }
```

and the map:

```
public class JournalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Journal>
    {
        public JournalMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.id);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.journalized_type)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            this.Property(t => t.notes)
                .HasMaxLength(65535);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("journals", "redmine");
            this.Property(t => t.id).HasColumnName("id");
            this.Property(t => t.journalized_id).HasColumnName("journalized_id");
            this.Property(t => t.journalized_type).HasColumnName("journalized_type");
            this.Property(t => t.user_id).HasColumnName("user_id");
            this.Property(t => t.notes).HasColumnName("notes");
            this.Property(t => t.created_on).HasColumnName("created_on");
        }
    }
```

Now when I try to perform a select on the journals database using LINQ:

```
return context.Journals.Where(c => c.journalized_id == task.id);

I see that the following query is created:

-       returnValue {SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`journalized_id`, 
`Extent1`.`journalized_type`, 
`Extent1`.`user_id`, 
`Extent1`.`notes`, 
`Extent1`.`created_on`, 
`Extent1`.`Issue_id`
FROM `journals` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`journalized_id` = @p__linq__0}    


 System.Linq.IQueryable<Synchronisation.Domain.Entities.Redmine.Journal> {System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<Synchronisation.Domain.Entities.Redmine.Journal>}
```

What I don't understand is where the "Issue_id" is coming from, this query is causing a EntityCommandExecutionException (Inner exception: {"Unknown column 'Extent1.Issue_id' in 'field list'"} )

When I manually add the Issue_id column this problem is fixed (this fix must be reverted, no changes to the database structure are ment to be made)

I have no clue where this "Issue_id" coming from, does anybody have an idea how to find this out?

Cheers,
Rick

Comment: Try editing your Edmx model in XML, and doing a search for `Issue_Id`, does it have anything in your model?

Comment: Yes it does, but not in the journals EntitySet, EntityType or EntityTypeMapping. And there is no relation defined between the journal table and other tables

Comment: Have you added references between the Journal and Issue that were not created by the power tool?

Comment: Ah yes I did :) I'll remove that refence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removed the custom reference between Journal and Issue (I had added a list of journals to my Issue class)

```
public List<Journal> Journals { get; set; }
```

After removing this list EntityFramework could figure out the query correctly again.