# Cannot get records with entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, sqlite

I have an SqLite db which have category table. Category table has 3 columns, Id: int, name: varchar, and ObjectID: int

I wrote entity for this table:

```
class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ObjectId { get; set; }
}
```

and I also have a context:

```
class DEContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions
            .Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to get categories with context.Categories I receive `System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException`:

> > SQL logic error or missing database\r\nno such column: Extent1.Object_Id

The query looks like:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
    [Extent1].[ObjectId] AS [ObjectId],
    [Extent1].[Object_Id] AS [Object_Id]
FROM [Category] AS [Extent1]} System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Category>
```

I don't know where the Object_Id is from. I don't have such column in db and I don't use such name in my whole project.

I use [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my mistake. I had List of categories defined in my Object entity, and that was causing the problem.

Related questions:

[Entity Framework trying to retrieve non existent column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546123/entity-framework-trying-to-retrieve-non-existent-column)

[EntityFramework tries to select a none existing column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084415/entityframework-tries-to-select-a-none-existing-column)